# Confused on kpss.test shows both "Trend" and "Level" are smaller than p-value R

Tags: r, time-series, kpss-test

I am fairly new to time series analysis. I am using hourly data for six months time period. My time series has seasonality every week. Per [Dr.Robert Hyndman](https://www.otexts.org/fpp/8/7)
I set up my time series variable and then did a kpss.test,

```
cooltemp = ts(training$vol,  frequency = 168)
checkl <- kpss.test(cooltemp, null = "Level")
checkt <- kpss.test(cooltemp, null = "Trend")
```

output of`checkl` was,

```
 KPSS Test for Level Stationarity

data:  cooltemp
KPSS Level = 4.0716, Truncation lag parameter = 13, p-value = 0.01
```

output of check `checkt` was ,

```
KPSS Test for Trend Stationarity

data:  cooltemp 
KPSS Trend = 1.24, Truncation lag parameter = 13, p-value = 0.01
```

There is a weekly seasonality in the data and I assume for checkt , it should be "p-value greater than printed p-value" for Trend.

The reason is, i checked with the example,

```
x <- 0.3*(1:1000)+rnorm(1000)
xt <- kpss.test(x, null = "Trend")
xl <- kpss.test(x, null = "Level")
```

The result of `xt` is,

```
KPSS Test for Trend Stationarity

data:  x
KPSS Trend = 0.042451, Truncation lag parameter = 7, p-value = 0.1
```

that shows that Trend station null hypothesis can be accepted. And the result of `xl` is

```
KPSS Test for Level Stationarity

data:  x
KPSS Level = 12.598, Truncation lag parameter = 7, p-value = 0.01
```

The result of null hypothesis level can be rejected.

I am confused on how to interpret in my case, where I get both are 0.01, where I have to reject both of my null hypothesis.

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, If you dataset contains hourly data then the frequency of the time series should be 24.

`cooltemp = ts(training$vol,  frequency = 24)`

Secondly, It is preferable for KPSS test, that you reject null hypothesis if `p-value < 0.05`. *p-value greater than printed p-value* only indicates that the value has been rounded off to two decimal points. Your value for `checkt` will not be greater that 0.05 even if the statement was printed in the console.

From the above outputs for `checkl` and `checkt`, we can say that your series is non-stationary on level and trend. You should consider differencing the time-series to make it stationary.

Since you know there is weekly seasonality in the series, therefore I would suggest taking a seasonal difference as in the following r code:

```
checkl <- kpss.test(diff(cooltemp,7), null = "Level")
checkt <- kpss.test(diff(cooltemp,7), null = "Trend")
```

---

If you wish to check the order of differencing and seasonal differencing are required to make the series stationary, you can try the following code:

`ns <- nsdiffs(cooltemp)
if(ns > 0) {
  xstar <- diff(x,lag=frequency(x),differences=ns)
} else {
  xstar <- x
}
nd <- ndiffs(xstar)
if(nd > 0) {
  xstar <- diff(xstar,differences=nd)
}`

Source: [Hyndman, R. J., & Athanasopoulos, G. (2016). 8.1 Stationarity and differencing. In Forecasting: principles and practice. Heathmont: OTexts.](https://www.otexts.org/fpp/8/1)

Comment: thank you for your answer and pointing out my mistake on frequency to set up at 7.Also, order of differencing also It helped me to find the seasonal differencing. I checked for stationary or non stationary with Dickey-Fuller test `adf.test(cooltemp, alternative = "stationary")`  and the result of `p-value` was smaller than 0.01, on the other hand, i checked `adf.test(cooltemp, alternative = "explosive")` and the `p-value` was much higher that 0.05. This way, I made sure that my timeseries is non-stationary.